# Can you have automatic numbering indexes hierarchies?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchy, multi-index

I am wondering if it is possible to have multiple indexes similar to the picture in which one of them (second level in my case) counts automatically?

I have the following problem that i have data which needs to be updated repeatedly and the data either belong to the category "Math" or "English". However I would like to keep track of the first entry, second entry and so on for each category.

Now the trick is that, I would like to have the second level index count automatically within the category, so that every time I add a new entry to a category "math", for example, it would automatically update the second level index.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Just have them as separate columns with the values added then `set_index` for your index

Answer (score 0):

You can `set_index()` using a column and a computed series.  In your case `cumcount()` does what you need.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"category":np.random.choice(["English","Math"],15), "data":np.random.uniform(2,5,15)})

df2 = df.sort_values("category").set_index(["category", df.sort_values("category").groupby("category").cumcount()+1])

df2
```

#### output

```
                data
category            
English  1  2.163213
         2  4.292678
         3  4.227062
         4  3.255596
         5  3.376833
         6  2.477596
Math     1  3.436956
         2  3.275532
         3  2.720285
         4  2.181704
         5  3.667757
         6  2.683818
         7  2.069882
         8  3.155550
         9  4.155107
```